# function format_type not supported on DBOS/SPU

Tags: sql, netezza

I am getting subject error when trying to run below query in Neteeza - Aginity

```
(SELECT 'TABLE1' AS TABLE_NAME, 'CHANGE_BY_CD' AS COL,(SELECT DATA_TYPE 
FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'TABLE1'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'CHANGE_BY_CD') AS COL_LEN, MAX(LENGTH(CHANGE_BY_CD)) AS MAX_LEN, CHANGE_BY_CD::CHARACTER VARYING(2000) AS VAL FROM SCHEMA1.A_TABLE1 
WHERE CHANGE_BY_CD IS NOT NULL GROUP BY CHANGE_BY_CD ORDER BY MAX_LEN DESC , CHANGE_BY_CD DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Error

```
ERROR:  function format_type not supported on DBOS/SPU
```

This error pops up after adding below part to the query

```
(SELECT DATA_TYPE 
FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'TABLE1'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'CHANGE_BY_CD') AS COL_LEN
```

Is there any solution to this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into an issue with what is called a "bridge query", which is a query that references system catalog tables (via views) and native Netezza tables.  In these sorts of queries it's not uncommon to run into a data type and function compatibility issues.

Not to get too deep into those weeds, I'll cut to the chase and say that if you resort to a case statement to resolve the data type you can avoid those issues in this particular case.

For CHARACTER, VARCHAR, NCHARACTER, and NVARCHAR you can subtract 12 from the value in ATTTYPMOD to get the character length of the column as defined in the DDL.

```
SELECT 'TABLE1'   AS TABLE_NAME,
   'CHANGE_BY_CD' AS COL,
   (
      SELECT data_type
      FROM (
            SELECT objname,
               attname,
               atttypid,
               ATT.ATTTYPMOD,
               CASE
                  WHEN atttypid=23 THEN 'INTEGER'
                  WHEN atttypid=16 THEN 'BOOLEAN'
                  WHEN atttypid=17 THEN 'BYTEA' 
                  WHEN atttypid=18 THEN 'CHAR'
                  WHEN atttypid=19 THEN 'NAME'
                  WHEN atttypid=20 THEN 'BIGINT'
                  WHEN atttypid=21 THEN 'SNALLINT'
                  WHEN atttypid=22 THEN 'INT2VECTOR'
                  WHEN atttypid=24 THEN 'REGPROC'
                  WHEN atttypid=25 THEN 'TEXT'
                  WHEN atttypid=26 THEN 'OID'
                  WHEN atttypid=27 THEN 'TID'
                  WHEN atttypid=28 THEN 'XID'
                  WHEN atttypid=29 THEN 'CID'
                  WHEN atttypid=30 THEN 'OIDVECTOR'
                  WHEN atttypid=210 THEN 'SMGR'
                  WHEN atttypid=700 THEN 'REAL'
                  WHEN atttypid=701 THEN 'DOUBLE'
                  WHEN atttypid=702 THEN 'ABSTIME'
                  WHEN atttypid=705 THEN 'UNKNOWN'
                  WHEN atttypid=1007 THEN '_INTEGER'
                  WHEN atttypid=1033 THEN 'ACLITEM'
                  WHEN atttypid=1034 THEN '_ACLITEM'
                  WHEN atttypid=1042 THEN 'CHARACTER(' || atttypmod -12 || ')'
                  WHEN atttypid=1043 THEN 'VARCHAR(' || atttypmod -12 || ')'
                  WHEN atttypid=1082 THEN 'DATE'
                  WHEN atttypid=1083 THEN 'TIME'
                  WHEN atttypid=1184 THEN 'TIMESTAMP'
                  WHEN atttypid=1266 THEN 'TIMETZ'
                  WHEN atttypid=1700 THEN 'NUMERIC'
                  WHEN atttypid=2500 THEN 'BYTEINT'
                  WHEN atttypid=2569 THEN 'NUCL'
                  WHEN atttypid=2570 THEN 'PROT'
                  WHEN atttypid=2522 THEN 'NCHAR(' || atttypmod -12 || ')'
                  WHEN atttypid=2530 THEN 'NVARCHAR(' || atttypmod -12 || ')'
                  WHEN atttypid=278 THEN 'NTEXT'
               END DATA_TYPE
            FROM DEFINITION_SCHEMA."_V_OBJ_RELATION"
               JOIN DEFINITION_SCHEMA."_V_ATTRIBUTE" ATT
               ON ATT.ATTRELID = DEFINITION_SCHEMA."_V_OBJ_RELATION".RELOID
               LEFT JOIN DEFINITION_SCHEMA."_T_ATTRDEF"
               ON (
                     ATT.ATTRELID = DEFINITION_SCHEMA."_T_ATTRDEF".ADRELID
                  AND ATT.ATTNUM  = DEFINITION_SCHEMA."_T_ATTRDEF".ADNUM
                  )
            WHERE (
                  ATT.ATTNUM                              > 0
               AND SUBSTR("NVARCHAR"(ATT.ATTNAME), 1, 1) <> '_'::"NVARCHAR"
               AND OBJTYPE                                ='TABLE'
               )
         )
         foo
      WHERE foo.objname = 'TABLE_1'
      AND foo.ATTNAME   = 'CHANGE_BY_CD'
   )
                                         AS COL_LEN,
   MAX(LENGTH(CHANGE_BY_CD) )            AS MAX_LEN,
   CHANGE_BY_CD::CHARACTER VARYING(2000) AS VAL
FROM TABLE1
WHERE CHANGE_BY_CD IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY CHANGE_BY_CD
ORDER BY MAX_LEN DESC ,
   CHANGE_BY_CD DESC LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was actually trying to compare  column actual length with the maximum data length of the column. In your solution I cannot see column length.

Comment: Looks like by using `_V_SYS_COLUMNS ` table can get the length with `COLUMN_SIZE `. I get the same error when try to retrieve `TYPE_NAME ` which is having both data type and length

Comment: Are you looking for char/varchar columns sizes in particular?

Comment: Yes mostly, because truncation could occur around those types

Comment: For character/ncharacter/varchar/nvarchar only, you calculate the size by reference ATTTYPMOD and subtracting 12.   I'll alter the code to show this example. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `V_RELATION_COLUMN` view provided by IBM in the `/nz/support/bin/SAMPLES` folder, which has the following definition

```sql
/*
Depending on how you use the view _V_RELATION_COLUMN, it might throw an
    ERROR:  function format_type not supported on DBOS/SPU

This view V_RELATION_COUMN is a duplicate of the view _V_RELATION_COLUMN
    (based on the 7.2.1.3-P2 release)
But it replaces the function FORMAT_TYPE( ) with some inline sql code in order
to bypass that problem.
*/

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  V_RELATION_COLUMN  AS

(
    SELECT
        R.OBJID,
        R.OBJNAME AS NAME,
        R.OWNER,
        R.CREATEDATE,
        R.OBJTYPE AS TYPE,
        R.DATABASE,
        A.ATTNUM,
        A.ATTNAME,
        A.OID AS COLID,
        T.DESCRIPTION,
 
        --(FORMAT_TYPE(A.ATTTYPID, A.ATTTYPMOD))::VARCHAR(200) AS FORMAT_TYPE,
        case when ATTTYPID =   20 then 'BIGINT'
             when ATTTYPID =   23 then 'INTEGER'
             when ATTTYPID =   21 then 'SMALLINT'
             when ATTTYPID = 2500 then 'BYTEINT'

             when ATTTYPID =  701 then 'DOUBLE PRECISION'
             when ATTTYPID =  700 then 'REAL'

             when ATTTYPID = 1266 then 'TIME WITH TIME ZONE'
             when ATTTYPID = 1083 then 'TIME'
             when ATTTYPID = 1184 then 'TIMESTAMP'
             when ATTTYPID = 1082 then 'DATE'
             when ATTTYPID = 1186 then 'INTERVAL'

             when ATTTYPID =   16 then 'BOOLEAN'

             when ATTTYPID = 1700 then 'NUMERIC(' || (ATTTYPMOD/65536) || ',' || MOD(ATTTYPMOD,65536)-12 || ')'

             when ATTTYPID = 1043 then 'CHARACTER VARYING(' || ATTTYPMOD - 12 || ')'
             when ATTTYPID = 1042 then 'CHARACTER(' || ATTTYPMOD - 12 || ')'

             when ATTTYPID = 2530 AND ATTTYPMOD = -1 then 'NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING'
             when ATTTYPID = 2530                    then 'NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(' || ATTTYPMOD - 12 || ')'

             when ATTTYPID = 2522 then 'NATIONAL CHARACTER(' || ATTTYPMOD - 12 || ')'

             when ATTTYPID = 2552 then 'ST_GEOMETRY(' || ATTTYPMOD - 12 || ')'
             when ATTTYPID = 2568 then 'BINARY VARYING(' || ATTTYPMOD - 12 || ')'

             ---- other/unknown data types
             when ATTTYPID =   17 then 'BYTEA'
             when ATTTYPID =   18 then 'CHAR'
             when ATTTYPID =   19 then 'NAME'
             when ATTTYPID =   22 then 'INT2VECTOR'
             when ATTTYPID =   24 then 'REGPROC'
             when ATTTYPID =   25 then 'TEXT'
             when ATTTYPID =   26 then 'OID'
             when ATTTYPID =   30 then 'OIDVECTOR'
             when ATTTYPID =  702 then 'ABSTIME'
             else 'UNRECOGNIZED DATATYPE(' || ATTTYPID || ',' || ATTTYPMOD || ')'
        end as FORMAT_TYPE,

        A.ATTNOTNULL,
        A.ATTTYPID,
        A.ATTTYPMOD,
        A.ATTLEN,
        A.ATTDISPERSION,
        AD.ADSRC AS COLDEFAULT,
        CASE WHEN (A.ATTLEN = -1) THEN (A.ATTTYPMOD - 12) ELSE INT4(A.ATTLEN) END AS ATTCOLLENG,
        A.ATTDELIM,
        (A.ATTZMAP = 1) AS ZMAPPED,
        R.OBJCLASS,
        R.RESTOREDOID AS RELRESTOREDOID,
        R.OBJDELIM,
        A.ATTVERSTATUS,
        A.ATTORIGOID,
        A.ATTRESTOREDOID,
        R.OBJDB,
        R.SCHEMA,
        R.SCHEMAID
    FROM
        (((_V_OBJ_RELATION R
                   JOIN _T_ATTRIBUTE A
                        ON ((A.ATTRELID = R.RELOID)))
                LEFT JOIN _T_ATTRDEF AD
                    ON (((A.ATTRELID = AD.ADRELID)
                               AND (A.ATTNUM = AD.ADNUM))))
            LEFT JOIN _T_DESCRIPTION T
                ON ((A.OID = T.OBJOID)))
    WHERE
        ((A.ATTNUM > 0)
            AND (SUBSTR("NVARCHAR"(A.ATTNAME), 1, 1) <> '_'::"NVARCHAR"))
)
UNION ALL (
    SELECT
        R.OBJID,
        R.OBJNAME AS NAME,
        NAME("CURRENT_USER"()) AS OWNER,
        R.OBJCREATED AS CREATEDATE,
        'TEMP TABLE'::"NAME" AS TYPE,
        D.DATNAME AS DATABASE,
        A.ATTNUM,
        A.ATTNAME,
        A.OID AS COLID,
        ''::TEXT AS DESCRIPTION,

        --(FORMAT_TYPE(A.ATTTYPID, A.ATTTYPMOD))::VARCHAR(200) AS FORMAT_TYPE,
        case when ATTTYPID =   20 then 'BIGINT'
             when ATTTYPID =   23 then 'INTEGER'
             when ATTTYPID =   21 then 'SMALLINT'
             when ATTTYPID = 2500 then 'BYTEINT'
 
             when ATTTYPID =  701 then 'DOUBLE PRECISION'
             when ATTTYPID =  700 then 'REAL'

             when ATTTYPID = 1266 then 'TIME WITH TIME ZONE'
             when ATTTYPID = 1083 then 'TIME'
             when ATTTYPID = 1184 then 'TIMESTAMP'
             when ATTTYPID = 1082 then 'DATE'
             when ATTTYPID = 1186 then 'INTERVAL'

             when ATTTYPID =   16 then 'BOOLEAN'

             when ATTTYPID = 1700 then 'NUMERIC(' || (ATTTYPMOD/65536) || ',' || MOD(ATTTYPMOD,65536)-12 || ')'

             when ATTTYPID = 1043 then 'CHARACTER VARYING(' || ATTTYPMOD - 12 || ')'
             when ATTTYPID = 1042 then 'CHARACTER(' || ATTTYPMOD - 12 || ')'

             when ATTTYPID = 2530 AND ATTTYPMOD = -1 then 'NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING'
             when ATTTYPID = 2530                    then 'NATIONAL CHARACTER VARYING(' || ATTTYPMOD - 12 || ')'

             when ATTTYPID = 2522 then 'NATIONAL CHARACTER(' || ATTTYPMOD - 12 || ')'

             when ATTTYPID = 2552 then 'ST_GEOMETRY(' || ATTTYPMOD - 12 || ')'
             when ATTTYPID = 2568 then 'BINARY VARYING(' || ATTTYPMOD - 12 || ')'

             ---- other/unknown data types
             when ATTTYPID =   17 then 'BYTEA'
             when ATTTYPID =   18 then 'CHAR'
             when ATTTYPID =   19 then 'NAME'
             when ATTTYPID =   22 then 'INT2VECTOR'
             when ATTTYPID =   24 then 'REGPROC'
             when ATTTYPID =   25 then 'TEXT'
             when ATTTYPID =   26 then 'OID'
             when ATTTYPID =   30 then 'OIDVECTOR'
             when ATTTYPID =  702 then 'ABSTIME'
             else 'UNRECOGNIZED DATATYPE(' || ATTTYPID || ',' || ATTTYPMOD || ')'
        end as FORMAT_TYPE,

        A.ATTNOTNULL,
        A.ATTTYPID,
        A.ATTTYPMOD,
        A.ATTLEN,
        A.ATTDISPERSION,
        AD.ADSRC AS COLDEFAULT,
        CASE WHEN (A.ATTLEN = -1) THEN (A.ATTTYPMOD - 12) ELSE INT4(A.ATTLEN) END AS ATTCOLLENG,
        A.ATTDELIM,
        (A.ATTZMAP = 1) AS ZMAPPED,
        R.OBJCLASS,
        R.RESTOREDOID AS RELRESTOREDOID,
        R.OBJDELIM,
        A.ATTVERSTATUS,
        A.ATTORIGOID,
        A.ATTRESTOREDOID,
        R.OBJDB,
        S.OBJNAME AS SCHEMA,
        R.OBJSCHEMAOID AS SCHEMAID
    FROM
        ((((_T_TEMP_TABLE_INFO R
                        JOIN _T_TEMP_TABLE_ATTR A
                            ON ((A.ATTRELID = R.OBJID)))
                    JOIN _T_DATABASE D
                        ON ((R.OBJDB = D.OID)))
                JOIN _T_OBJECT S
                    ON (((((R.OBJSCHEMAOID = S.OBJID)
                                       AND (R.OBJDB = S.OBJDB))
                                   AND (S.OBJSCHEMAOID = 4))
                               AND (S.OBJCLASS = 4941))))
            LEFT JOIN _T_ATTRDEF AD
                ON (((A.ATTRELID = AD.ADRELID)
                           AND (A.ATTNUM = AD.ADNUM))))
    WHERE
        (A.ATTNUM > 0)
);
```